# excel 2007 choosing column in right-most tab

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that has 6 worksheets.  The first five worksheets are for the weeks in a month -- to report to our client weekly (i.e. at the beginning of the month, worksheets 2-5 are not filled; second week of the month worksheets 3-5 are not filled; often, fifth worksheet is not filled at all for the month).  The 6th worksheet contains some new information or summarizes info from the other worksheets.  One column though, needs information from the most recent weekly worksheet.  Right now the formula in that worksheet is:

```
='Week 1'!G7
```

which is at cell G7 of the fifth worksheet, reading from G7 from the first worksheet (named, as I'm sure you'll know 'Week 1'.

Is there a way I can tweak this formula to take the right-most or most recently filled G7 cell on the first 5 worksheets?

Comment: By 'tabs' you mean 'Worksheets'?

Comment: Yes -- that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF('Week 5'!$G$7<>"",'Week 5'!$G$7,IF('Week 4'!$G$7<>"",'Week 4'!$G$7,IF('Week 3'!$G$7<>"",'Week 3'!$G$7,IF('Week 2'!$G$7<>"",'Week 2'!$G$7,'Week 1'!$G$7))))
```

Comment: I don't get an error with Taosique's answer.  Are you sure you copied ALL the formula, including ALL the closing brackets at the end?

Comment: @Chris Walsh I'm using Desktops from sysinternals and didn't quite copy/paste everything correctly the first time trying to switch back and forth.  I'm going to accept this answer when I can (< 1 minute).  I'd upvote you but I don't have enough rep to do so yet.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to check for the presence of a value in the equivalent cell in each worksheet.
Let's say you want the latest value of cell G7 and that your worksheets are named 'Week 1' through to 'Week 5'.  I would use an IF statement:

```
=IF('Week 5'!G7<>"",'Week 5'!G7,IF('Week 4'!G7<>"",'Week 4'!G7,IF('Week 3'!G7<>"",'Week 3'!G7,IF('Week 2'!G7<>"",'Week 2'!G7,IF('Week 1'!G7<>"",'Week 1'!G7,"")))))
```

The "" at the end is a default value to use if NO G7 cells have data in them.

Comment: Finally got the rep to upvote you.  Your answer was as good as the accepted one, just a little after -- so thanks!